# What is the best font to use for Thai Language in Flex Mobile Applications?

Tags: apache-flex, fonts, thai

I am facing issues with Thai language in flex mobile applications. I am using Tahoma font and facing issues in TextInput

Whith Tahoma font text Offset setting to far from the starting of the text input .

Can any one suggest me the best font to use with Thai language ?

Many thanks in advance for your help .

Regards,

Kamal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue with Mobile TextInput skin . Here is the fix for the issue

[TextInput Skin Issue Fix](http://www.hesslerdesign.com/blog/flash/correcting-the-flash-builder-4-5-mobile-textinputskin-component/)